# Collaboratively develop a WordPress site

Tags: git

I'm going to develop a website using Wordpress with a colleague.
How can we manage it so that we can develop it together at the same time?
I heard git is not right for Wordpress

Comment: I love git and there is an official (developer) git repo now too, but this question is going to be "too broad" and "subject to opinion" I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Git is definitely a valuable tool for collaborative WordPress development. Have a look at some talks on WordPress.tv about using Git: http://wordpress.tv/?s=git

If you understand a bit of French, this talk ([video](http://wordpress.tv/2014/03/10/amaury-balmer-industrialiser-son-ou-ses-projets-wordpress/) / [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/herewithme/industrialiser-son-ou-ses-projets-wordpress-wordcamp-paris-2014)) by Amaury Balmer is terrific. Some of his recommendations:

- Use an automated deployment method (running your own, or using an off-the-shelf service). There are many deployment tools that interface with Git/Github.
- Use Travis CI to automatically test if your commits break anything.
- Make use of branches to work on several issues - every issue can be a git branch.

Answer (score 0):

Go with http://bitbucket.org for private project works at free of cost.  Which is limited with team members.

It has 
   * issues tracker 
   * hip-hop chat
   * wiki
   * branches and commits.

You can use  `Source Tree` to manage your git's.  You can create public and private git's.

I hope for the private projects.  instead of github,  i prefer bitbucket.

Comment: Indeed, Bitbucket is awesome, it's what I use to host my commercial projects. Github is where my public code goes.

Answer (score 0):

If you work on WordPress in the recommended manner, I.e. creating templates or extending existing ones with self-contained custom functions, then you'll only need to check-in the `wp-content/themes/yourthemename` directory into Git, not the whole WordPress installation. It should then be easy to collaborate on.